# Need to figure out what to do with sparsematrix

Tags: java, sparse-matrix, circular-list

So I have to make a sparse matrix base on circular linkedlist... but not sure how to start... So far I know i gotta have a Node class where I going to have something like 
Node class include those fields:

```
{
int value;
Node next, down;
int row,column;
}
```

[Here an image of how sparse matrix for my assignment look like](http://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/545517_3321439974804_2136675241_n.jpg)

I think I have to make the first node, which is enter, but not sure what next...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each node has references to its nearest neighbour in "forward" cartesian directions, so:

```
public class Node {
    Node right, down;
}
```

would be a reasonable start.

The fact that the matrix is sparce or circular is irrelevant if you use this design.

Typically, the main program would hold a reference to the "first" node, which is arbitrary but a reasonable choice would be the top left node.

Comment: My spec sheet require me to make a Node class with 2 Node fields: right and down. I cant do up and left.